# XML generator get only one link

Tags: php, html, xml, generator, sitemap

i have a problem when i try to make a sitemap XML with a generator or a my script Crawler.

In some of my site (example: http://www.lanuvola.it) the generator find only one link, the homepage of the site.

Why the generator can't find all pages? It's a site make with my CMS but i don't think is this the problem, because i have several website that use this CMS and the XML generator works fine.

Can you help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Okay, should we guess?

Comment: And so, what you mean?

Comment: @LorenzoBelfanti give a practical part, what you are doing actually to get the all pages, so we can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You blocked all languages. So there is just "LANGUAGE NOT FOUND". I think your site is italian, but most of the generators are in english. You have to open the site for english language that it will work...